# Rewrite Adminhtml Model doesn't work

Tags: adminhtml, overrides

I need to rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Catalog/ListSort.php

my config.xml :

```
...
<global>
   <models>
       <mymodule>
            <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
       <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <system_config_source_catalog_listsort>My_Module_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListSort</system_config_source_catalog_listsort>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
     </models>
 </global>
 ...
```

app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Catalog/ListSort.php

```
<?php
 class My_Module_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListSort
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListSort 
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        var_dump('TEST');
    }
}
```

Also My_Module already rewrite lot of models.

Please help me to find what i'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the tag name from `<system_config_source_catalog_listsort>` to `<system_config_source_catalog_listSort>`

Comment: That's it ! Didn't think about it since we remove the first capital letter in the tagname ... thanks a lot !

Comment: you are supposed to remove the capital letters, but only from the start of the file name. The ones in the middle have to be there.

Comment: I will definitively remember it

Comment: hey Lanks its not necessary you have to use only first letter in capital. Magento convention is always use lowercase letter in xml file when your are overriding module. I have do practically & below code .  <product_list_upsell>Sourav_Jain_Block_Upsell</product_list_upsell>